# How do I migrate from the Google Reporting API to the Admin SDK Reports API?

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-reporting-api, google-admin-audit-api

On April 20, 2015 the Google Reporting API and Admin Audit API are scheduled to be shut down. I need to migrate my code to use the Admin SDK Reports API instead. How do I go about this migration?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/migrate) determine you how to translate calls to the Reporting API and Admin Audit API to their corresponding calls in the Admin SDK Reports API. Refer to the Admin SDK Reports API’s documentation for information on how to download libraries and get started.

Be aware that support for older authorization methods ([ClientLogin](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps), [AuthSub](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthSub), and [OAuth 1.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth_ref)) are also scheduled to be shut down at the same time. If you are currently using these methods please also migrate to [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) at the same time.